# Script to search for specific file names in multiple directories

Tags: batch-file

I have a list of file names spread across multiple directories on a shared network drive.  I'd like to write a script that will search all subdirectories for specific file names, then copy them to a directory on my local PC.  I don't want to keep directory structure in tact - I want to have all the files from any directory copied to one location.

I've been trying variations of this batch file, but it doesn't copy anything:

```
set FILELIST=C:Directory\FileNames.txt
set FOLDERPATH=C:Directory\FolderPaths.txt
set DESTPATH=C:\Directory\Test

for /f %%X in (%FILELIST%) do call :COPY_FILES "%%X"
goto :eof

:COPY_FILES
for /r %FILESPATH% %%I in (%~1) do echo xcopy "%%I" "%DESTPATH%%%~pnxI"

pause
```

The FileNames.txt file contains all the files I need by name and extension only (ex: Voicemail.wav). The FolderPaths.txt contains all possible network paths where the file names might be located (ex. \Server\Share\Mail\00, \Server\Share\Mail\01, \Server\Share\Mail\02, etc.)  Both text files are delimitated by line break.

Thanks for any advice you can provide.

Comment: Ever thought of doing the same with xcopy or robocopy ?

Comment: there is a spelling mistake in first for, FILELIST var has to I's

Comment: Sorry for the spelling mistake in my post.  In my actual batch file, it's correct.

Comment: Please confirm if C:Directory\FileNames.txt contains a list of file names and C:Directory\FolderPaths.txt contains a list of directories.

Comment: Yes Paul, that's correct.